# Extract 'Roles' from a JWT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have created a token and sent it to my client application (ReactJS).

```
{
  UserId: "1",
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "Unset",
  http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Array(2), 
  exp: 1531116565,
  iss: "http://www.example.com", 
…}
```

The role item looks like this:

```
[ {0: "User"}, {1, "Admin"} ]
```

I'm not sure why my roles item is named as a URL. But what I am trying to do is work out if the JWT indicates the user has an Admin role.

How can I check the array of roles, for 'Admin'?

Comment: are the items in the array objects or strings and something is rendering the output weirdly?  the index like key and the comma instead of colon in the second item is making it difficult to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
const roles = [
  {0: "User"}, {1: "Admin"}
];
let isAdmin = false;
roles.map( role => {
  let r = Object.values( role )
  if ( r[0] == 'Admin' ) {
    isAdmin = true
  }
})

console.log( isAdmin );
```

Comment: Thanks @GansPotter - I'm not sure how to reference the roles though, from my jwt, as the 'name' of the property seems to be 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role'.

Comment: @Craig, if role always comes with url and with valid json then this might help you
-->
const token = {
  'UserId': '1',
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name': "Unset",
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role': [{0: "User"}, {1: "Admin"}], 
  'exp': 1531116565
};
let roles = []
Object.keys( token ).forEach( key => {
if( key.match( /.*role$/) ){
  roles = token[ key ]
}
})
let isAdmin = false;
roles.map( role => {
  let r = Object.values( role )
  if ( r[0] == 'Admin' ) {
    isAdmin = true
  }
})
console.log( isAdmin );

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("x-access-token");

const role = JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split(".")[1])).role;
```